# Background image for animated gif built in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I'm very new to working with node.js and packages like express and canvas, so I apologise if there are any glaringly obvious mistakes in my code and if I take a bit to understand any questions or solutions.

I'm currently working on customising a version of - https://github.com/Nooshu/node-countdown-gif. A canvas generated countdown timer for use in emails. My customisations are minimal, all I've done thus far is load in a font and add some more from the url to query off of.

The problem I'm having is that, rather than a flat colour or gradient background, I'd like to, if possible, load in an external image as a background image behind the timer, it looks like it should be possible but I just can't get it to work.

This is the code block that generates the visual of the timer with a flat colour background.

```
if(typeof timeResult === 'object'){
            for(let i = 0; i < this.frames; i++){
                // extract the information we need from the duration
                let days = Math.floor(timeResult.asDays());
                let hours = Math.floor(timeResult.asHours() - (days * 24));
                let minutes = Math.floor(timeResult.asMinutes()) - (days * 24 * 60) - (hours * 60);
                let seconds = Math.floor(timeResult.asSeconds()) - (days * 24 * 60 * 60) - (hours * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60);

                // make sure we have at least 2 characters in the string
                days = (days.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + days : days;
                hours = (hours.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + hours : hours;
                minutes = (minutes.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = (seconds.toString().length == 1) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

                // build the date string
                let string = [days, 'd ', hours, 'h ', minutes, 'm ', seconds, 's'].join('');

                // paint BG
                ctx.fillStyle = this.bg;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);

                // paint text
                ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
                ctx.fillText(string, this.halfWidth, this.halfHeight);

                // add finalised frame to the gif
                enc.addFrame(ctx);

                // remove a second for the next loop
                timeResult.subtract(1, 'seconds');
            }
        }
```

I need this background image to generate  during every loop, otherwise the timer layers on top itself each loop. I've attempted 2 different methods I've seen for loading in an external image. The first I couldn't get to work at all, with no image showing. See method :

```
let img = new Canvas(this.w, this.h);
                img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/600x200.png';
                img.onload = function(){
                  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.w, this.h);
                }
```

I've had more success with my second method but still cannot get it to work. If placed earlier in the code (prior to the for loop) it successfully loads the image but the timer does not show. If placed within the for loop it throws the following error for each iteration of the loop. This is the code block, followed by the error. Note: This error only appears when placing the code block within the for loop.

```
   let imgUrl = 'https://via.placeholder.com/'
    loadImage(imgUrl + image + '.png').then(image => {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 600, 200)

        const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png')
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
        res.send(buffer)
    })
```

```
Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
```

Is anyone able to support me in solving my issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this out.

Earlier on in my code is an init function that prepares my timer for build, moving the onload function within this function, then passing the output to an encode function allowed to work as expected when placing a drawImage function within the for loop defined above -

```
  if (imageBgSrc !== null) {
           let img = new Canvas.Image;
                img.src = imageBgSrc;
                img.onload = function() {
                $this.encode(timeResult, img, cb);
    }
        } else {
            this.encode(timeResult, null, cb);
        }
```

```
encode: function (timeResult, image, cb) {

// Other code

if (image !== null) {
                    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height)
                }
// Other code
}
```